# usb transfer speed reduces with transfer progresses

Tags: 19.04

Usb transfer speed reduces with transfer progresses.My system is Asus R558U with intel i5-7200u 4Gb/1TB and running on  19.04.

Comment: This is normal behavior as copied bytes are initially buffered to RAM quickly and then progress slows as RAM is flushed to non-volatile storage device which 100 times slower than the volatile RAM.

Comment: If you move many files with small sizes it takes longer time. Archived file transfer speed is much better.

Comment: Are you trying to move files from `NTFS` to `Ext4`?